# Copying ROS packages from Virtual Nao to Actual Nao

Tags: nao, compilation, packages, virtualbox, gentoo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am following the tutorial (I can't publish links! The title is: "Installing ROS Indigo onto NAO with help of virtual-nao") from the ROS Wiki, which involves compiling ROS to a virtual Nao, before copying files to the real robot. I had some excellent help with a problem from yesterday, so was hoping someone might be able to help once again.

I am now at the stage of copying packages from the virtual Nao to the actual Nao. Packages such as rosversion, rospkg, lz4 etc. appear to have been copied across successfully. However, the package "Netifaces" is giving me problems now. I have attempted to copy multiple folders/packages called "netifaces" or "netifaces-0.10.4-py2.7-linux-i686.egg" into the following locations - all of which give me the same (or very similar) errors:

```
/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
/home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

It is worth mentioning these locations are where I have copied all of the other packages, unless suggested otherwise in the Wiki.
However, when attempting the following commands:

```
$ ssh nao@<Nao_IP>
$ source install_isolated/setup.bash
$ roslaunch nao_bringup nao.launch force_python:=true
```

the following error is displayed (there is no cut&paste from the VM - I have to type so please forgive spelling errors):

```
... logging to /home/nao/.ros/log/3c8e50e2-9959-11db-b7b2-0001c005b836/roslaunch
-nao-13384.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. 
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
;/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/share/nao_bringup/nao.launch
DEPRECATED IN HYDRO:
  The <include> tag should be prepended with 'xacro' if that is the intended use
  of it, such <xacro:include ...>. Use the following script to fix incorrect 
  xacro includes:
    sed -i 's/<include/<xacro:include/g' 'find . -iname *.xacro'
DEPRECATED IN HYDRO:
  The <include> tag should be prepended with 'xacro' if that is the intended use
  of it, such <xacro:include ...>. Use the following script to fix incorrect 
  xacro includes:
    sed -i 's/<include/<xacro:include/g' 'find . -iname *.xacro'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosla
unch/__init__.py", line 279, in main
    p.start()
  File "/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosla
unch/parent.py", line 258, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosla
unch/parent.py", line 206, in start_infrastucture
    self._load_config()
  File "/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosla
unch/parent.py", line 121, in _load_config
    self.config = roslaunch.config.load_config_default(self.roslaunch_files, sel
f.port, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosla
unch/config.py", line 458, in load_config_default
    config.assign_machines()
  File "/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosla
unch/config.py", line 218, in assign_machines
    if [m for m in machine_unify_dict.itervalues() if not is_machine_local(m)]:
  File "/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosla
unch/core.py", line 91, in is_machine_local
    local_addresses = ['localhost'] + rosgraph.network.get_local_addresses()
  File "/home/nao/nao_ros_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosgra
ph/network.py", line 215, in get_local_addresses
    import netifaces
ImportError: No module named netifaces
```

Once again, I am using VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 4.2.10_Ubuntu r84101.

The OpenNao image is "opennao-vm-2.0.1.54.ova"

Any help, please feel free to suggest something.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173426/copying-ros-packages-from-virtual-nao-to-actual-nao/) by [Dominic](https://answers.ros.org/users/5875/dominic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can you check your usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth file and see if the line
./netifaces-0.10.4-py2.7-linux-i686.egg is present ?
Otherwise the location on your real nao should be /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ but you can also copy them into /home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages if your root is full. Just don't forget to modify the easy-install.pth file accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0